# Color of button(bootstrap button) not changing in netbeans?

Tags: css, jsf

This is the css of a info button(from bootstrap) and its in my style.css file in resources in resources in netbeans. I am using a maven/web application with Java Server Faces framwork.:

```
.btn-info {
background-color: #d60d8c;
border-color: #d60d8c;
}
```

this is the button code in a JSF page:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right" id="logg"><a href="logga.html">Sign in</a></button>
```

The button code is in a bootstrap navbar. The border of the button is using the `border-color: #d60d8c;`, but the background color of the button does not change according to `background-color: #d60d8c;`.

Why is that? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @BalusC because everything else is styled according to my style.css file. well, everything except for the button color and also the navbar color. When the I wrote the original code in html in Notepad++, everything was ok, but when i tried to make it xhtml and working with jsf 2.2, this coloring problem occured.

Comment: @BalusC sorry for the wrong information, but my style.css is in Webpages/resources/css. And this is how I loaded the style.css file: `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />` . It seems to be a problem when trying to change the color of the two bootstrap components I used, the navbar and the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming css is loaded properly)

Your css selector is only class-specific. Probably, somewhere in your project there are more specific css selectors, matching the button. (you can see, what selector "wins" for property using Chrome developer tools (F12), tab Elements-Computed.[image]

So, you need to be more specific.

For example, add [`id` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors):

```
#logg.btn-info {
    background-color: #d60d8c;
    border-color: #d60d8c;
}
```

If it won't fix your issue, try to [play with specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html)

Comment: This didnt exactly work for me, but I looked at the Chrome developer tools as you said, and found a strange way to recolor bootstrap components. So, thank you for your help!